# Joomla 3: GANTRY_BOOTSTRAP_CANT_FIND_LIBRARY

Tags: joomla3.0

I downloaded a free template for my Joomla website in localhost. I installed the template in the extensions. When i view it in site, i am getting the following error.

```
GANTRY_BOOTSTRAP_CANT_FIND_LIBRARY
```

I do not know how to solve it? Is there any one who come across this issue can help me..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally this means you tried to upgrade Gantry and it encountered a problem while running the upgrade which broke it.  Generally I have seen this when there is a file/folder permission issue.  Check permissions and re-install gantry framework.  http://gantry.org/downloads